# ROS msg including image and related variables related to that image

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, msg, image, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to create a publisher which can publish an image along with a few strings, integers and arrays containing different information about the image (like number of objects, bounding boxes, name of the objects inside image etc).

Up until now, I am successful to publish image using the following command:

```
  pub_msg = bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(img, "bgr8")
  pub.publish(pub_msg)
```

But I dont understand how to incorporate rest of the data with this image. If I create custom ROS msg, how to add all these information variables along with and image data. Please guide me or suggest me some tutorial where I can get some related help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288006/ros-msg-including-image-and-related-variables-related-to-that-image/) by [xaggi](https://answers.ros.org/users/34544/xaggi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to create a custom message which includes the `sensor_msgs/Image` as well as the additional data that you want. Those could be primitives (e.g. `int8`) or other compound messages (e.g. `geometry_msgs/Polygon`, not quite sure if this specific one helps, though).

There is [a tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv) about how to create custom m essages. Then you need to fill the respective fields and adapt your publisher accordingly.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0